Object from thymeleaf form gets saved to database way before executing repository save method
I have a fullstack application with a thymeleaf frontend, spring backend and a mariadb database. The strange problem occurs when I try to update an Object via a thymeleaf form.
The class of the Object looks like this (simplified):
@Entity
@Table(name = "[tenants]")
@ApiModel( value = "Tenant", description = "Tenants resource representation" )
public class Tenant implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "[tenant_id]")
    @ApiModelProperty( value = "tenantId", required = false )
    private long tenantId;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("tenant")
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "[rent_start]")
    @ApiModelProperty( value = "rentStart", required = true )
    @NotNull(message = "Rent start is required")
    private Date rentStart;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "[rent_end]")
    @ApiModelProperty( value = "rentEnd", required = true )
    @NotNull(message = "Valid to is required")
    private Date rentEnd;
    
}

The Car class looks like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "[car]")
@ApiModel( value = "Car", description = "Cars resource representation" )
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "[car_id]")
    @ApiModelProperty( value = "carId", required = false )
    private long carId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("cars")
    private Tenant tenant;

}

In the backend there is the usual structure of a TenantView class, which calls a TenantService, which calls the TenantRepository which extends CrudRepository. My Problem occurs when updating a Tenant. Here are the methods that get called when Updating a tenant:
TenantView:
@RequestMapping(path="/update-tenant", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateTenant(@Valid @ModelAttribute("tenant") Tenant tenant, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ResponseMessage message = null;      
        
        try { 
            tenantService.save(tenant);
            // Neues ModelAndView mit Redirect verwenden, um das POST-Redirect-Get-Pattern umzusetzen
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/view/tenants/all");
            message = new ResponseMessage("message.success.title", "tenant.message.success.update.text", "message.success.color");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);            
            LOGGER.debug("Update tenant was successfully");
            return modelAndView;   
        } catch (SQLException sex) {
            LOGGER.error(sex.getMessage());
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/view/tenants/update-tenant/");
            message = new ResponseMessage("message.error.title", "tenant.message.error.update.sql.text", "message.error.color");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
            return modelAndView;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());            
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/view/tenants/update-tenant/");
            message = new ResponseMessage("message.error.title", "tenant.message.error.update.unkown.text", "message.error.color");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
            return modelAndView;
        }
}

TenantServiceImpl:
public Tenant save(Tenant tenant) throws SQLException {
        // some logic modifying the cars
        ...
        return tenantRepository.save(tenant);
}

TenentRepository: CrudRepository
Here is my Problem: I have a Tenant who rents two cars (I guess not important here) and his rentStart is the 01-01-2024 and the rentEnd is 12-31-2024. He is saved in my database like this. I want to update rentStart to 06-06-2024 and rentEnd to 06-30-2024.I have set a breakpoint in the first first line of the TenantView (ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();). When I now look in my database the new dates (06-06-2024 and 06-30-2024) are already saved in the database. After that the code executes as expected and saves again. I have no idea how to even begin to search the problem here. I tried setting breakpoints on every occasion "tenantRepository.save(tenant);" is called but with no luck.
Some information about me and the code provided: I am a junior dev with about a year of experience. So I do not know if you need more or different information. The code I work on is production code so I can not publish it here one to one, so I trimmed it down and changed the class names. From my example data it should not be a problem, because the result is the same either way, regardless if it was saved to the database before the actual save in the repository or not. But in the real code also the cars get updated in the service based on some logic that breaks when the tenant gets saved prematurely. I tested if this logic has something to do with the problem and commented it out, so that the real repository save method looks exactly like the one provided. The problem persists.
I do not expect a quick fix (wouldn't complain either) because I think the problems lies somewhere deeper. I would like to know if someone has experienced something similar and has an idea where and how to start searching for the cause of the problem.
Thank you very much in advance!

Hi can you provide your html template please?

What are you doing in your GetMapping method? Are you using Hibernate and directly returning the database entity object in the html?

Thanks for reading my question and trying to help! I just found a solution. You can see it below and maybe you can explain why this works.

Before going to bed yesterday (when else?) an idea came to my mind.
I named the method in the TenantService "save". What if there is some problem with this name? This name has its fixed use in TenentRepository extends CrudRepository. Today I tried renaming the method to something else and it actually fixed my problem.
So I conclude for myself: If you use the save method from CrudRepository, do not name a service method, where some additional logic than just calling the repository is happening,just "save", but something else.
Something to note is, that I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. My Coworker uses MacOs. He did not experience this issue.
I still have no idea why this happens. Maybe someone who is more proficient than myself can explain further.
